# Facebook PHP SDK v4 - Proper folder structure anyone?

Tags: php, facebook, gruntjs, composer-php, directory-structure

I have used composer to install the facebook php sdk. From my base directory I have 3 dirs
node_moules (contains bootstrap dir)
vendor (which contains facebook and composer dirs, and autoload.php)
pages (which contains index.php - pages I serve)

So the Facebook SDK lives in `base\facebook\php-sdk-v4\`

Firstly, is my folder structure decent? I also noticed that I have another node_modules folder in `base\node_modules\bootstrap\node_modules`. This feels wrong

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it, assuming the 'php-sdk-v4' directory is simply the Facebook PHP SDK structure. Are your concerns regarding your entire project structure or some specific part of it?